# Integer value corrupt when casting from void*

Tags: c, typedef, void-pointers

I have the following code:

```
typedef void* EstimatedValue;

EstimatedValue myFunction()
{
    int myVal = 16;
    EstimatedValue value = &myVal ;
    return value;
}
bool intLessOrEqual(EstimatedValue value1, EstimatedValue value2)
{
    return *(int*)value1 <= *(int*)value2;
}
```

And this main function:

```
int x = 8;
EstimatedValue val = myFunction();
EstimatedValue x1 = &x;
intLessOrEqual(x1, val);
```

However, the value of the second argument (the one that is created in the function) is corrupt inside the `intLessOrEqual` function (the value is -858993460).
If I try to access `*(int*)val` inside the `main` function it works ok. What could be the reason for this behavior? 
What can be done in order to avoid this behavior

Comment: Can you add the definitions of Element and date also?

Comment: @P.W I've updated the code

Comment: `myVal` is declared local to the function `myfunction`. You are returning the address of a local variable. This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myVal` is created on the stack in the `myFunction` function. And you are returning an address to it. This leads to undefined behaviour because the value of `myVal` can change once it goes out of scope.

What you can do is create memory for value like this:

```
EstimatedValue value = malloc(sizeof(int);
```

Assign the value:

```
*value = 16;
return value;
```

In `main` after all the processing, you have to free that memory like this:

```
  free(val);
```

Comment: What would you do in order to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Updated the answer to avoid the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
EstimatedValue myFunction()
{
    int myVal = 16;                  // local variable
    EstimatedValue value = &myVal ;
    return value;                    // now release where myVal was
}
```

By the time this function have returned back to its caller, the memory where the local variable `myVal` is saved will have been released, and `val` in `EstimatedValue val = myFunction();` essentially is pointing a memory space that is not occupied, i.e. anything else can be overwritten on it. Then what happens next is unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks, so making EstimatedValue as one of the input parameters of the function will solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, you can essentially get a buffer passed as the argument of `myFunction()`.